# sap ui5 planning calendar - title text size

Tags: sapui5

I am creating the appointments in planning using the following XML tags,

I wanted to reduce the appointments the size of the title in each appointments - title="{title}".

Also wanted to increase the height of appointment to show more data.

```
<appointments>
                    <unified:CalendarAppointment
                        startDate="{start}"
                        endDate="{end}"
                        icon="{pic}"
                        title="{title}"
                        text="{info}"
                        type="{type}"
                        tentative="{tentative}">
                    </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                </appointments>
```

Comment: Saying 'wanted' means that you wanted to in the pass but no longer. Pedantry aside, assuming you mean want, you need to supply more information. Increase the size of the title where? On a web page, in an application? Have you written any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign CSS class to your Planning calendar and modify the respective CSS classes to suit your requirements.
CSS Classes:

1. sapUiCalendarApp: controls the height of each appointment.
2. sapUiCalendarAppTitle: controls the font-size of title of each appointment.

So, let us assign our own class to our planning calendar so other developer code is impacted ( or the entire library CSS is not updated)

CSS code:

```
        .myCalendar .sapUiCalendarApp {
            height:5rem;
        }

        .myCalendar .sapUiCalendarAppTitle {
            font-size:.5rem;
        }
```

XML CODE:
We need to add our CSS class to our planning calendar:

```
<PlanningCalendar
            class='myCalendar'
            id="PC1"
            startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"
            rows="{path: '/people'}"
            appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
            appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"
            showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false">
            .......
            <appointments>
                    <unified:CalendarAppointment
                        startDate="{start}"
                        endDate="{end}"
                        icon="{pic}"
                        title="{title}"
                        text="{info}"
                        type="{type}"
                        tentative="{tentative}">
                    </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                </appointments>
               .............
```

You can modify the above CSS classes to suit your requirements. Let me know if any additional information is required.